# Error with NetBeans Android plugin

Tags: android, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I am currently developing an Android app and i am using Netbeans 6.9.1 and nbandroid 1.0 beta. I have installed Android SDK and configured everything but when i create a simple project and try to build it gives an error

```
Creating output directories if needed...
Created dir: C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication2\bin
Created dir: C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication2\gen
Created dir: C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication2\bin\classes
Compiling aidl files into Java classes...
Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and RenderScript bytecode...
Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
compile:
C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:384: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication2\bin\classes
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication2\bin\classes.dex...
=C:\Documents was unexpected at this time.
C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:472: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Documents and Settings\KeSoLK\My Documents\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:203: apply returned: 255
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

what can be the problem? and how to solve it.

Thanks !!

Comment: What is your problem in `Eclipse`? Try `Eclipse`.. the best environment for android development http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just encountered the same issue. It seems to be related to spaces in path at the time *ant* tries to start *dex.bat* with parameters:

```
<exec executable="${dx}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="--dex"/>
            <arg value="--output=${basedir}/${intermediate.dex}"/>
            <arg value="--positions=lines"/>
            <arg path="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</exec>
```

The project won't run if `${basedir}`, `${intermediate.dex}` or `${build.classes.dir}` contain spaces.

Parameters for batch files have to be encapsulated with "...". But how to do this when *ant* starts the batch file?

My quick workaround was to move the folder of my netbeans android project (not all projects) to a path that doesn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is a 'space in path' problem of Android SDK.

Other than that I'd strongly recommend you to update to newer version of both NetBeans and NBAndroid plugin.