# Problem in android

Tags: java, android, netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

i am using netbeans 7 and i am runing this code

```
package com.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and i am getting error

```
Creating output directories if needed...
Compiling aidl files into Java classes...
Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and RenderScript bytecode...
Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
compile:
G:\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:384: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 1 source file to D:\java programs\Android\HelloWorld\bin\classes
Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\java programs\Android\HelloWorld\bin\classes.dex...
=D:\java was unexpected at this time.
G:\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:486: The following error occurred while executing this line:
G:\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:203: apply returned: 255
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to some spaces in any path

look for the same here
[Error with NetBeans Android plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152904/error-with-netbeans-android-plugin)